# Find the professor who is paid less than atmost 2 other professors

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Professors(
    Name varchar,
    Salary money
)
```

I have this sql question to answer:

1. Find the professor who is paid less than at-most 2 other professors
2. Find the third highest paid professor.
3. Is the problem in Question 1 the same as in Question 2?

My understanding is that they are *not* the same.

Because in the first part we need to find a professor whose salary can be less than by at most 2 others salary. If there are many professors on the top with same salary this will return nothing.

Is my understanding correct.? If not could anyone help me out with this with sample data and query.

Comment: Actually i didn't get what you need, can you show your query and desired results ?

Comment: @Japongskie i just wanted to know whether the two questions i posed are one and the same. If not I wanted a query sample to answer the first question

Comment: Well, question 1 includes the highest and second highest paid professors (it should have been phrased in plural though: "professors"). There is nothing demanding a minimum number if higher paid professors. Question 2 clearly wants the third ranking professor. Here you might have to clarify to what happens when there are a number of equally paid professors ...

Answer (score 1):

If the salaries are all different the result would be the same but if the table looks like this:

```
Name - Salary
A - 1
B - 1
C - 2
D - 3
E - 4
F - 5
```

Question 1 would result in Professor C with salary 2 but question 2 would result in Professer D with salary 3.

But what happens if the table looks like this:

```
Name - Salary
A - 1
B - 1
C - 1
D - 1
E - 2
F - 3
```

Now question 1 gets a little bit tricky because the answer to question 1 would result in having the same salary OR having more than 2 professors with a higher salary.

If this is an assignment from school the answer might be in the actual data but either way I'd ask the person who made this question for a clarification.

Comment: It is an assignment and it is expected for me to provide a query which can work on any type  of data.

Comment: You seem to have listed the salary *ranking* and not the salary *itself*, right?

Comment: yea i suppose. I understood that :)

Comment: @cars10 salary or salary ranking. It works the same. One professor makes more than the other, that is the important part. If it's 2000$, or 1 unit (which was my intention in my post).

Comment: @Jefecito: OK, having accepted that then the answer to Q1 with regards to the first table shoud have been "D" and not "C", or am I wrong here (both, "E" and "F" earn more than "D")?

Comment: @cars10 I think in general the question is very vaguely described and the best solution would be for OP to ask what the originator wants. Having said that in question 1 we are looking for a professor who earns less than at most two other professors, if the two professors over me have the same or a different salary doesn't matter i.e. the answer (as I understand it) should be Professor C. I could also make statements that the answer to question 2 is the same but I'm trying to figure out what the originator might have wanted (which might be dangerous so that's why I recommended OP to ask him).

Comment: @Jefecito so as of i understand now, for Q1 we can sort the table rows and just select the 3rd row in it.

Comment: @human That is how I understand it. But it doesn't take into consideration (nor does the question state it) if the three highest professors have the same salary.

Comment: @Jefecito oops question is ambiguous again as it clearly states professors salary should be LESS than at most 2 professors

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios, the RANK function should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 similar approaches to the solution assuming the third best salary is what matters (regardless how many professors have the same salary). I think this is valid for a real life situation. I hope it helps.

```
;WITH temp AS (
    SELECT Name, Salary,
        DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS byrank
    FROM Professors
    )
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE byrank = 3

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Salary,
        DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS byrank
    FROM Professors
) AS t1
WHERE byrank = 3;
```